# Why do I not get enough reputation to start with to be able to downvote?

Tags: discussion, down-votes, association-bonus

I'm pretty sure the whole reputation system is put in place so that newcomers learn the different concepts before actually being allowed to use them, and that as a member of one of the other sites in the group you get a higher initial reputation score when you first register to one of the sister sites (like the new Stack Exchange sites that come out of private beta).

That said, why do I get 100 initial rep score for registering, but need 125 to be able to downvote?

Comment: A time when this is particular frustrating is when trying to down-vote answers on your *own question* on a new site. As a 200+ user on other sites, I'm quite familiar with when it's appropriate to down-vote answers, yet I'm forced to just write comments with my `101` rep. Sure... I could amass a measly 30 points to address this issue, but isn't that the whole point of the 100 rep boost?

Comment: related: [The association bonus should not enable users to vote on every site](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183109/the-association-bonus-should-not-enable-users-to-vote-on-every-site)

Comment: most reasonable explanation is given in the [answer in duplicate question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/228244/165773 "here"): **"you could downvote an answer exactly twice before you lose the privilege if you only have the reputation from the association bonus..."**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because [you should be focusing on upvotes](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-down). More importantly, it is to prevent "drive-by" downvotes - the rep system is used as a rough gauge on how much the community "trusts" you.

Comment: I think that's a better explanation for the rep system than 'the system trusts you'. It is actually the community that assigns the trust.

Comment: Actually, I was trying to contribute to the site by downvoting a wrong answer.

Comment: @Dave Van den Eynde: If you downvote, you can contribute even more by adding your own answer, or commenting on why you downvoted the post.

Comment: @In silico I know that, silly, but I'm unable to downvote.

Comment: Nobody prevents drive-by upvoting? I find drive-by upvoting ***much*** worse than drive-by downvoting. ......

Answer (score 4):

maybe to get some (just very little) *feeling* of how the new site works before being able to downvote.

I mean someone who is *good* at programming ([Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)) is not automatically that *good* at let's say [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/).

For sure you must not be an expert to be able to recognize a bad answer, or to decide that an answer is not useful (for you). But getting 25 points of reputation isn't that hard, not for a theme you are interested in.