# Didn't you regret the "Association Trust"?

Tags: discussion, reputation, association, association-bonus

I was absolutely happy and also surprised, when I could see that after reaching 200 reputation points, I got +100 reputation for every sub-account. It's a very kind decision.

It also means that if someone reaches 200 reputation, you trust him so strongly that you clear most of the beginner's limits for them.

However, is 200 reputation enough for you to trust someone that strongly? Isn't it a bit few?

Comment: Which privileges do you find problematic with regards to the association bonus?

Comment: The privileges given are easily earned and cover only basic functionality.

Comment: The logic is that if you've learned the ropes on one of our sites, you will know how to act on another site. There's no reason to subject you to the new-user restrictions because you are *not* a new user. What privileges do you think are granted too early as a result of the association bonus?

Comment: @AmericanLuke That isn't the case. You get the bonus on all SE sites that you create an account on.

Comment: @CodyGray maybe the upvote privilege could be pushed higher

Comment: I actually find the result a bit *low* on "derived" sites, being far over the 200 rep on other sites. Like I don't fancy interacting on Ask Ubuntu and Ask Different a lot, while in my opinion those are just specialized Super User children.

Comment: No, I don't regret it. Starting with 101 points is just enough. Note you won't be able to downvote until gaining 24 more points and will still see ads until you reach 200 on the associated account.

Comment: It has been criticized that association bonus give ability to vote: [The association bonus should not enable users to vote on every site](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183109/the-association-bonus-should-not-enable-users-to-vote-on-every-site)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [privileges bestowed upon you](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) with the association bonus are pretty minimal.

They are only meant to keep complete newbies from misusing the site by accident because they don't understand the unique rules or attitude on SO.

Since the person has 200 rep on another site in the network, this basic trust is warranted.

Answer (score 2):

200 rep points is pretty easy to come by with a minimum of effort.  Kicking in an extra 100 points only gives you one additional [privilege](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes), but it gives you a kickstart to make it to the next level.  It's a nice reward for someone who shows a little effort.

Comment: Not that easy IMO. It takes time at least. I just wasn't sure that this is enough, but GEOCHET's answer makes sense.