# Per site stats related to association bonus

Tags: support, statistics, association-bonus

I would like to get some statistics to help me better understand the role of association bonus at different sites.

For a given site, I would like to know:

- How many users were granted bonus based on this site reputation.
- How many users have been granted a bonus from other sites, how many of them have a positive on-site reputation "balance", and how does amount of users with bonus compare against ones having upvote privilege.
- Of users with bonus, which site has granted most and how many (what percent of users with bonus has got it from top-granting site)

As the SE network is huge, I would not object if the data is limited to, say, 20-30 top-traffic sites, although fuller stats would be much appreciated.

Comment: example of discussion where I expect requested stats to be useful: [The association bonus should not enable users to vote on every site](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/183568/165773) -- _"Without data... it's rather difficult to tell how much of an issue this is, or what sites ate affected..."_

Comment: another example where I expect requested stats to be helpful: [Prevent questions on Hot List from being upvoted by casual visitors (only rep is from association bonus)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238420/165773)

Comment: Hmm, looks like you just gave away your association bonus with this bounty. :)