# Registered Voter; a site-wide voting privilege

Tags: feature-request, reputation, voting, privileges

New privilege:

**Registered Voter** -5k(?) combined rep. You are trusted enough to vote on *any* post that you're reading, whether or not you have signed up for the specific site.

---

Unwilling to sign up for my 43rd account and in an effort to avoid (going insane) my own self from posting where I shouldn't; I just want the ability to vote. *NOT* the ability to post or comment (of which I cannot help myself once the rabbit hole is opened).

There are a few sites like this that hold interest for me. [Academia](https://academia.stackexchange.com/) is the main one where my two cents would be foreign currency. Time and again I find myself reading their posts with nothing more to add then *wow* (+1). However, if I had an account there I might be tempted to (make noise) *exchange my money*...

Apparently SE wants me in a position capable of making noise if I'm to vote. (?)

---

@Oded This is different from the association bonus (which gives you the ability to upvote and comment) in that, that's exactly what I don't want. 'Signing up' or 'logging in' let me do *many* things. Including then having to police my own comments that I left in a less than *keen* state of mind. Half of my accounts are probably to upvote someone's comment and that was it. Now it's on my list of places I have to keep cleaner than I found it. *Not* signing up for the rest of all of SE is a personal roadblock to make that job easier. I just find it funny SE lets you vote *and* contribute with the same level of 'trust'. One would find it easier to identify good content than to produce it themselves, no?

This didn't make my final cut:

> Votes make Stack Exchange go-around. Absolutely nothing (other than the attempt to cling to my own sanity) is keeping me from signing up, voting, asking, answering, or commenting *anywhere, ever* ; SE already 'trusts me' (auto +100). Is the problem that down-votes have to be accountable for? Well, then take them off their highest site's rep.

The problem, as it turns out, is that *network* profiles don't have privileges.

Comment: Are you serious?

Comment: @nicael Why not, this is nothing the site association bonus doesn't do for you anyway.

Comment: Can you expand on what makes this different to the association bonus (which give you the abilities to upvote and comment)?

Comment: @Oded OP is lazy to log in.

Comment: @Oded You can't downvote with the association bonus (not saying that's a bad thing though)

Comment: Also - to get to +5000, you just need one site with > 200 rep, then register on 47 other sites (so, you get 4,800 in association bonus, plus the 200).

Comment: @Yannis - for good reason.

Comment: @Oded Sure. Now how about we also remove upvoting from the mix? I don't see the point in letting people who haven't earned any rep on the site upvote.

Comment: You know that the whole concept of privileges is site specific, right? And you must be logged in to have privileges? So this request it utterly pointless.

Comment: @ShadowWizard So then we first need privileges for SE *network* profiles.

Comment: @Mazura not going to happen since the network profile is not a real account. You can try asking for such a thing in a separate request.

Comment: @Yannis ...or at least [delay granting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238420/prevent-questions-on-hot-list-from-being-upvoted-by-casual-visitors-only-rep-is#comment781411_238420) 'em that privilege _"wanna vote? stick with us! (for at least a day or two)"_

Comment: @Mazura looks like the real problem is your addiction to take part in sites once you have account. I fear Stack Exchange is not responsible for this and can't really do anything, apart of maybe add a warning when creating new account same way cigarettes have warnings.

Comment: -1 We have actually had quite an opposite request: [Prevent questions on Hot List from being upvoted by casual visitors (only rep is from association bonus)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238420/189976)

Comment: @tohecz It's not my fault people knee jerk on the hot tab and abandon all sensible criteria for voting. Although that's a very good reason this will never happen.

Comment: Well, they do not abandon criteria for voting, they simply generate a very biased noise, which is given by the system. And even if they were behaving "stupid", it doesn't change the fact that their "stupidity" has to be considered when building up the criteria. (Disclaimer: I don't mean "stupid" to be offensive, I just can't find a better word for it.)

Comment: @tohecz probably "ignorance" would be a better word for it. Or, if you don't mind using few words instead of one, "lack of familiarity with site topics and quality norms"...

Comment: @gnat To build on your ideas, "lack of familiarity with the site" is actually very precise, self-explanatory and describes the problem really well. It as well clearly shows that this vote bias is not exactly their fault.

Comment: "[All I ask is this. As you browse Stack Overflow, when you see a good question: vote for it.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9508/why-arent-people-voting-for-questions?rq=1)" ... I'd love to...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is for good reason. Privileges are site-specific, not network-wide. Other people have explained this many times, but I'll summarize again: Just because you're an expert at cooking (for example) doesn't mean you should go moderate gaming.

If you want to exercise your right to upvote/comment on sites that you're currently not a part of, is it so hard to hit login, give your openID, and create the account? You get the association bonus, and boom -- you're done.

No need to continue using the account, though of course you are free to.

Comment: I'm not "to lazy to login", I don't want to deal with account numbers 43-97... You and Shadow hit it on the head I guess: *cannot haz*.