# Ideas to help new users to get involved in the community

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, guidelines

I've come from a simple observation with some coworkers about how difficult it is to get enough reputation to be able to become part of the community, mostly when you use SO just to find the answer you're looking, without being able to up-vote or comment anything. I made a proposition which was rejected there: [Discussion about pro and cons for allowing up-voting to very new users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247512/discussion-about-pro-and-cons-for-allowing-up-voting-to-very-new-users/247519#247519)

But the problem is still there and I would like to propose another solution for it.

I remember a talk I had with a collegue about SO, my friend told me that the system was "dumb", because he needed reputation to be able to vote or comment, and he wasn't able to get any since he couldn't comment on other topics while he knew the answer and so he couldn't get any reputation.

Obviously, my friend didn't know it was possible to `suggest edits`, well, I can't blame him, I didn't know either when I was a SO newbie.

So, I'm thinking maybe the problem isn't the system, but maybe it's because users don't know how to use it properly. And I think that edit suggestion is a good way to start to get reputation actually, but you have to know it's possible.

I don't know if nowaday it's explained in a better way than at the time, but since this talk happened only three months ago, I'll assume it's still a common issue.

**One possible solution** would be to add a new feature in the website, which would automatically send whether tutorial link like this: https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour to users who are like 1 month old without enough reputation. The idea would be just to send reminders about how to use SO correctly, how to get enough reputation to be part of the community. Somehow guide the users, because it doesn't currently, most of the time people ask questions about how to get reputation, or so, because they don't understand the system, because the system *is different* than the usual Q&A websites and *because* they need to be guided.

So, the idea is an email and/or a notification with a link whether explaining how does SO work, or maybe more focused on the user depending how much reputation he has (if <15 then explain how to *suggest edits*, if <30 then explain that they can post comment as well to get more reputation and so on). So I think that would be useful to send such guide after 7d, 1m, 3m, 6m, 1year. What do you think?

The idea is to guide users so they understand how to use SO the right way. And I don't think it is done well enough yet.

Sadly, *suggested edits* aren't for everyone, you may never have issue to express yourself in English, but I garantee you that for non-native English people, it is really not an easy thing to decide to *suggest an edit* when you aren't even able to make a simple sentence without mistake, so I don't believe it's a solution that works for everyone to get involved in the community. But I don't have any solution about that, maybe you will.

*Btw, I use **SO** because that's what I usually use, but I believe this would apply to all StackExchange sites.*

Comment: If your friend knew the answer, but didn't post it, that's not the system being dumb

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you're saying. What answer? What I meant is that he didn't know how to get reputation, it wasn't obvious enough to him and he didn't ask ou search for it. And even if he had known, he wouldn't probably have used *sugest edits* due to his lack of english grammar.

Comment: "he knew the answer and so he couldn't get any reputation." - This makes no sense. If he knew the answer, why didn't he... you know... post an answer?

Comment: Well, he didn't have the permission to do so. I think he had 8 points at that time... If I remember correctly.

Answer (score 4):

I think there is a limit to how much we should spoon feed and potentially over-communicate with new users, and so I think your "7d, 1m, 3m, 6m, 1year" idea is not as useful as simply reminding people who seem to be missing the point that the [Tour](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tour) exists by including a magic link of `[Tour]` in comments to them on an "as needed" basis.

That magic link does not work in a question or answer but saves lots of typing in comments.

Comment: If other people share this kind of link with new users it would have a better impact than automatically sent notifications/email. But if these people do not ask *(don't have time, don't think about asking, get bored, there are plenty of reasons)*, then they would not know and in this case I think that these automatic notifications/email are useful to guide them. About the frequency, that's just an example.