# The association bonus should be adequate for downvoting

Tags: feature-request, down-votes, privileges, association-bonus

I was reading an answer on a SE site where I wasn't yet registered. It was unhelpful, so I register to downvote the answer. I couldn't, because you need 125 reputation to downvote.

The association bonus should be adequate for this privilege, so I'm asking to either lower the reputation requirement to 100, or up the association bonus to 125.

Comment: Why 100? Why not just 0? Any user with no rep can make the claim, "it was unhelpful, why can't I downvote it?"

Comment: @djechlin The association bonus indicates that the user knows at least the basics of how a SE site works.

Comment: For down-voting, you're registering to the site?  seems strange more me :( I would suggest you to add a comment pointing there mistake in that Q or A.  Still not satisfied then flag it.

Comment: @Praveen I don't see what's strange about wanting to downvote wrong answers. Flagging it is pointless and should not be done.

Comment: Not like that.. I meant *registering to the site inorder to downvote a wrong answer.*  Yep flagging is not the right option unless it fall under a proper reason..

Comment: Also, until you've earned the privilege to down-vote on a site, you can comment at, what, 15 rep? So the association bonus is enough to let you leave a comment pointing out that an answer is wrong (and how). This is actually more constructive than down-voting alone, as the author can argue or fix exactly what you stated, rather than demanding who down-voted and why.

Comment: related: [The association bonus should not enable users to vote on every site](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183109/the-association-bonus-should-not-enable-users-to-vote-on-every-site)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The only way I can see the current policy being legitimate is to mitigate some effect where experienced users on one site can react and say "Blech! I don't like this" on any other site, without bothering to be a part of the community or of people answering questions. Why should you get to downvote when you're not actually part of the community of people answering good questions and trying to avoid bad ones? It's a very strange delegation of labor.

The one answer to that question is, "To show other users it's a bad answer." But why do *they* care *you* think it's a bad answer when you have no expertise in the subject area? Ideally downvotes come from people who know something on the subject, first.

But you do know something about Windows phones. Just like someone who has been a programmer for 20 years and joins StackOverflow knows something about programming. But can't downvote anyway. So, **You think you know enough about Windows Phone to downvote? Prove it! Answer a question or two.** That's really all this is about.

For completeness, on the other hand, there's the entirety of, say, christianity.SE, where I read the responses and generally react, "Wow this is total B.S." and just want to downvote everything. Fortunately, I can't, and the best measure of this is whether I can put out a couple decent answers by *their* standards (No.) Similarly, I really shouldn't be allowed to vocalize over downvotes my opinions on parenting when I really have no idea what I'm talking about.

Comment: [Like you mentioned here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228242/the-association-bonus-should-be-adequate-for-downvoting#comment748088_228243), right now I can downvote whatever I feel like downvoting on SO without knowing a single thing about the subject. Anyway, I guess the possible downsides outweigh the possible benefits or avoidance of frustration.

Comment: @Stijn but I think Martijn is right - Python and C++ agree on what a fact is; programming and parenting do not.

Answer (score 26):

If the privilege was at 100, you could downvote an answer exactly twice before you lose the privilege if you only have the reputation from the association bonus. So you would need to put it even lower than 100.

But I don't think this is a good idea at all, having 200+ reputation on a single site does not mean you're necessarily qualified to judge the answer quality and downvote on every other site. I think it makes a lot of sense to require users to participate a bit on each site before they can go around and downvote.

Comment: Good point about losing the privilege, I hadn't thought about that.

Comment: Regarding your second paragraph, indeed I am not necessarily qualified to judge an answer. But in this particular case, I am.

Comment: @Stijn But one particular case isn't enough to base a policy decision on

Answer (score 11):

Downvoting requires *some* knowledge about the culture of the site; the association bonus only gives you access to privileges that are universal across the network.

Comment: The site in question is [Windows Phone SE](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/). I have such a phone, so I know when an answer is not correct. Why would I need to gain knowledge about the site's culture?

Comment: I don't have such a phone. I wouldn't have the first idea when downvotes are suitable on that site.

Comment: How much do you know about the Islam or Christianity sites? How do they handle downvoting there?

Comment: Is it possible to have a technically accurate or inaccurate answer on those sites? Bad examples.

Comment: @Stijn: No, that makes them *excellent* examples. If we lower the downvote privilege to 100 points instead of 125, you can take your Stack Overflow bonus and thinking you know how those sites work, start downvoting. But as you say, those sites work differently *because* you cannot just apply an accuracy metric.

Comment: So what you're saying is you'd rather stop someone from downvoting an incorrect answer instead of having possible abuse of downvotes?

Comment: and  yet you can upvote everywhere just from the assoc bonus.

Comment: @Stijn: 24 points is a very low barrier; get to know the site a little before deciding to downvote. Yes, that may seem like a pain when the other site covers a subject you happen to know about, but that doesn't extend to the whole network.

Comment: @MartijnPieters do you program in ObscureLanguage? Why are you qualified to downvote those questions on SO? We can make a reasonable claim that if you're experienced on SO you know enough to downvote on many sister-technical sites. Probably not Islam or Christianity where facts have a different meaning.

Comment: @djechlin: the barriers are not perfect, but the differences between a ObscureLanguage question and Python questions (where I do have knowledge) are smaller than the cultural differences between sites.